# How to get class instances in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a class called Post that has many initiated instances (i.e. `Post.new(:name => 'foo')`).

Is there a way to retrieve all the instances of that class by calling something on it?
I'm looking for something along the lines of `Post.instances.all`

Comment: You could probably store a list of reference manually that you update from the constructor... but I'm curious why you would need to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Illustrating both alphazero's and PreciousBodilyFluids answers:

```
class Foo
  @@instance_collector = []
  def initialize
    @@instance_collector << self
    #other stuff
  end
  def self.all_offspring
    @@instance_collector
  end
end

a = Foo.new
b = Foo.new

p Foo.all_offspring  # => [#<Foo:0x886d67c>, #<Foo:0x886d668>]
p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).to_a # => [#<Foo:0x886d668>, #<Foo:0x886d67c>] #order is different
```

Comment: if a instance got destoried, will this `@@instance_collector` get updated.

Comment: @Vijay short answer is no, because there is no LOC removing the object from the array.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [ObjectSpace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html) to retrieve all instantiated objects of a given class:

```
posts = []
ObjectSpace.each_object Post do |post|
  posts << post
end
```

**This is almost certainly a bad idea**, though - for example, it will also load Post instances that are still in memory from earlier requests that haven't been garbage-collected. There's probably a much better way to get at the posts you care about, but we'll need more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

Override new; keep count; expose property.

Comment: +1 Short, sweet, to-the-point.