# Ruby: Array of Objects/Classes

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

I am not a ruby expert and this is giving me trouble. But how Would I go about creating an array of objects/classes in ruby? How would initialize it/declare it? Thanks in advance for the help.

This is my class, and I want to create an array of it:

```
class DVD
  attr_accessor :title, :category, :runTime, :year, :price

  def initialize()
    @title = title
    @category = category
    @runTime = runTime
    @year = year
    @price = price
  end
end
```

Comment: since it's within a class and I want other methods within the class to access it, I tried:

    @@movies = Array DVD.new

but quickly found out that didn't work.

Comment: You mean you want to create an array with the class instances?

Comment: Check if this is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365638/how-to-get-class-instances-in-ruby

Answer (score 20):

Ruby is duck typed (dynamic typing)
And almost everything is an object, so you can just add any object to an array. For example:

```
[DVD.new, DVD.new]
```

will create an array with 2 DVDs in it.

```
a = []
a << DVD.new
```

will add the DVD to the array. Check the [Ruby API for the full list of array functions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html).

Btw, if you want to keep a list of all the DVD instances in the DVD class you can do this with a class variable, and add it to that array when you create a new DVD object.

```
class DVD
  @@array = Array.new
  attr_accessor :title, :category, :runTime, :year, :price 

  def self.all_instances
    @@array
  end

  def initialize()
    @title = title
    @category = category
    @runTime = runTime
    @year = year
    @price = price
    @@array << self
  end
end
```

now if you do

```
DVD.new
```

you can get the list of all the DVDs you have created so far:

```
DVD.all_instances
```

Comment: Not almost everything is an object, *everything is an object*. Also, in general, class instance variables should be preferred over class variables.

Comment: Except really blocks are objects: `def f &block; block; end; f {}`. Which returns, well, *an object*.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall yes, like that they are converted to a proc, but when you have to yield for it, it is not an object :) therefore not everything, but almost everything is an object.

Answer (score 9):

`two_DVD = Array.new(2){DVD.new}`

Comment: The first time I tried this: Array.new(2, DVD.new) and this ended up creating 2 copies of the same object. Then I found your answer "Array.new(2){DVD.new}" and found it to create 2 unique objects, which is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In order to create an array of objects in Ruby:

1. Create the array and bind it to a name:

   ```
   array = []
   ```
2. Add your objects to it:

   ```
   array << DVD.new << DVD.new
   ```

You can add any object to an array, at any time.

If you wish to have access to every instance of the `DVD` class, then you can rely on [`ObjectSpace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html):

```
class << DVD
  def all
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).entries
  end
end

dvds = DVD.all
```

---

By the way, the instance variables are not being initialized correctly.

The following method call:

```
attr_accessor :title, :category, :run_time, :year, :price
```

Automatically creates `attribute`/`attribute=` instance methods to get and set the value of the instance variables.

The `initialize` method, as defined:

```
def initialize
  @title = title
  @category = category
  @run_time = run_time
  @year = year
  @price = price
end
```

Sets the instance variables, despite taking no arguments. What effectively happens is:

1. The `attribute` reader method is called
2. It reads the unset variable
3. It returns `nil`
4. `nil` becomes the value of the variable

What you want to do is pass the values of the variables to the `initialize` method:

```
def initialize(title, category, run_time, year, price)
  # local variables shadow the reader methods

  @title = title
  @category = category
  @run_time = run_time
  @year = year
  @price = price
end

DVD.new 'Title', :action, 90, 2006, 19.99
```

Also, if the only required attribute is the `DVD`'s title then you can do it this way:

```
def initialize(title, attributes = {})
  @title = title

  @category = attributes[:category]
  @run_time = attributes[:run_time]
  @year = attributes[:year]
  @price = attributes[:price]
end

DVD.new 'Second'
DVD.new 'Third', price: 29.99, year: 2011
```