# Handle Arrays of self in Class initialize method

Tags: ruby, arrays, initialization, self

Let's say I define class:

```
Class Product < Struct.new(:field1,:field2)
```

and the corresponding `new` method, which parses an input `string` into the attributes of this class:

```
def initialize(string)
    splitted=string.split(',')
    @field1=splitted[0]
    @field2=splitted[1]
end
```

I want the same `new` method to parse additional classes, including `Product` and anything that responds to `to_s`:

```
def initialize(string)
    case
    when string.is_a?(String)
        splitted=string.split(',')
        @field1=splitted[0]
        @field2=splitted[1]
    when string.is_a?(Product)
        @field1,@field2=string.deal
    when string.respond_to?(:to_s)
        @field1,@field2=Product.new(string.to_s).deal
    else
        raise RuntimeError,"Cannot understand product '#{string}' of class '#{string.class}'.", caller
    end
end

def deal
    return @field1,@field2
end
```

Now I also want this new method to handle Arrays:

```
productarray=Product.new(["some field,another field","name, surname",:"up, down",Product.new("something, anything")])
```

My initial guess was to add another `when` clause to the `new` method:

```
when string.is_a?(Array)
    return string.map{|s| Product.new(s)}
```

But that doesn't work.

Questions:

- How to get a class `initialize` method to handle Arrays of `self` (as explained above)?
- It doesn't seem very "rubyish" to have the sort of `case`/`when` structure in `new` to deal with every different class; is there any other option?
- How come when string is a product, I can't change the value of self and use the much simpler code `self=string` and have to go through all the trouble of `deal`ing?

References:

[Ruby: Array of Objects/Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532844/ruby-array-of-objects-classes)

Comment: Why does `Product` have to convert the input? Wouldn't it be much easier to pass the two attributes and handle conversions at the caller side? `Product.new(str1, str2)` or `Product.new(*string.split(','))` or `Product.new(product.field1, product.field2)`

Comment: @Stefan; I think that's a matter of preference. Your way is easy on the code, my way is easy on the coder. When I call `Product.new`, I don't care what `string` is. Besides, I implement once how to deal with a certain class and I am sure it will be used consistently every time `Product.new` is called (for better or for worse).

Comment: What do you expect to get from `Product.new(["some field,another field","name, surname"])`? An array of `Product` instances? This is impossible, since `new` method can only return one instance

Comment: @lobanovadik: Yes, I wanted an Array of `Product`s. So, i gather from your comment that what I want to do is impossible. That's one answer. Thanks.

Comment: This code is a mess of bad design decisions. You can make use of the adapter pattern here instead of those 'case' statements. Also, it doesn't make sense for an object to create other objects. You need a separate class that will be a 'factory' for producing objects. Learn more about design patterns, it should help your code a lot.

Comment: @daremkd, thank you for your criticism and pointing me towards adapter patterns.

Comment: which version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a slew of design decisions. First, use the Adapter pattern for converting a "Product" or a "String" to list of args that your Product class can recognize:

```
class Product < Struct.new(:field1,:field2)
  def deal
    return field1, field2
  end
end


class StringToFieldsAdapter < Struct.new(:string)
  def run
   string.split(',')
  end
end

class ProductToFieldsAdapter < Struct.new(:product)
  def run
    product.deal
  end
end
```

Let's test these adapters:

```
string_adapter = StringToFieldsAdapter.new('hey,there').run #=> [hey, there]
product_adapter = ProductToFieldsAdapter.new(Product.new(*StringToFieldsAdapter.new('one,two').run)).run #=> [one, two]
product_from_string = Product.new(*string_adapter) # the splat * just turns the [hey, there] array into arguments
product_from_product = Product.new(*product_adapter) #=> #<struct Product field1="one", field2="two">
```

Now, in your example with the array, you don't really want to accept an array into your Products. You want some method which will accept an array and create a new object out of each element.

For this, I'd make a class which will recognize which adapter to use and then another class which will actually create the objects (be a factory):

```
arr = ["some field,another field","name, surname","up, down",Product.new(*StringToFieldsAdapter.new("something, anything").run)]

class AdapterRecognizer < Struct.new(:object)
  def run
    case object
      when String then StringToFieldsAdapter
      when Product then ProductToFieldsAdapter
    end
  end
end


class ProductFactory < Struct.new(:array)
  def create_objects_from_each_array_element
    array.map do |element|
      adapter_to_use = AdapterRecognizer.new(element).run
      Product.new(*adapter_to_use.new(element).run)
    end
  end
end

p ProductFactory.new(arr).create_objects_from_each_array_element #=> should produce bunch of products
```

I've made adapters for only a string and a Product, you can extend it easily for symbols etc. For example, adding a symbol is just a simple instance of adding a new adapter class:

```
class SymbolToFieldsAdapter < Struct.new(:symbol)
  def run
    symbol.to_s.split(',').map(&:to_sym)
  end
end
```

and then adding another 'when' to the Adapter recognizer:

```
when Symbol then SymbolToFieldsAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks @daremkd. I flagged your post as the correct because it answers my question. However, lets forget for a minute about ProductFactory class (which is actually the most important bit) and the initialization method always returns the same class. I'm struggling to understand the conceptual difference between both ways (yours and mine) of branching the initialization of `Product`, according to the class of the `string` (or `field1`, `field2`, `string`, ... in your case). I see all the elements I implemented concisely in one method spread over several classes in your answer.

Comment: It's called the single responsibility principle. You'd get it once you write some bigger piece of software and have problems to maintain it. Your product class does too much. Would a "Product"  convert its arguments so it can later work with them? The product job is to be a product and respond to product-related methods. This whole principle is called "Single responsibility principle".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the order of the `when`s. Since pretty much everything in ruby responds to `to_s`, particularly `Array`, your array object gets caught before the last statement and tries to handle it as a string.
Edit: The issue is you  can't return meaningfully from an initializer, you can use it as a means to stop the program from runnning the following statements but what you return isn't used by `.new`. You can on the other hand use a class method to construct a list of objects for you as below. It is nicer however to have a factory for this purpose, but this also works.

That being said, as @daremkd mentions, it doesn't feel like a very good design decision to do this. Since you handle all these special cases you open up your code to quite a few possible bugs in future and more importantly make the mental model of this method quite complicated.

```
class Product
  def initialize(field1, field2)
    @field1 = field1
    @field2 = field2
  end

  def self.new_from_parameters(string)
    case 
    when string.is_a?(String)
      splitted=string.split(',')
      Product.new(splitted[0],splitted[1])
    when string.is_a?(Product)
      string
    when string.respond_to?(:to_s)
      Product.new_from_parameters(string.to_s)
    else
      raise RuntimeError,"Cannot understand product '#{string}' of class '#{string.class}'.", caller
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not clear from my post but the `when string.is_a?(Array)` would come before the `when string.respond_to?(:to_s)`, otherwise there'd be the problem you identify. This idea doesn't work because, as @Stefan and @daremkd pointed out, the `initialize` method returns single instances of the same class.

Comment: I don't think that should stop it from work it, initialize will return one and that's not a problem, since the `map` will call it for each element in the array, and return 1 `Product` at a time.

Comment: @Stefan_Dorunga: find a MWE [here](http://pastebin.com/2bNT2j6K) and try it yourself. Tested on `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: That is very strange. If you lot at a much simpler example it disproves that http://pastebin.com/0M5t9Efc . Still not quite sure why it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: @Stefan_Dorunga: In my opinion your MWE over-simplifies the issue. Find [here](http://pastebin.com/etE5Pkkz) the closest I could get to your example.

Comment: Sorry, got confused and didn't realize we were returning from an initialize. You could instead have a class method as a constructor along the lines of what I've updated in the answer above

Comment: @JoaoEncarnacao thanks for the edit, changed the answer to reflect it. Sadly you don't get points since the reviewers decided you were wrong.