# Find max value in a class in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

I've tried for several hours making this work.

i have this code where i have around 20 different persons, with different ages and names.

how can i make ruby searching through all the ages and show the highest age as and integer

i've been searching a lot, but cant seem to make it work. i've even tried to make it sort the numbers and the print the last age, which must be the highest number

```
def initialize(firstname, familyname, age)
  @firstname = firstname
  @familyname = familyname
  @age = age
```

Best regards

Comment: You need to show more of your code, including where/how all the persons are defined.  Also, use the formatting mechanism for code blocks (see help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end
```

And an array like this:

```
people = [Person.new(10), Person.new(20), Person.new(30)]
```

**Finding the maximum age**

You can get the ages with [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
people.map { |person| person.age }
#=> [10, 20, 30]

# or shorter

people.map(&:age)
#=> [10, 20, 30]
```

And the maximum value with [`Enumerable#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
people.map(&:age).max
#=> 30
```

**Finding the oldest person**

Or you could find the oldest person with [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
oldest = people.max_by { |person| person.age }
#=> #<Person:0x007fef4991d0a8 @age=30>

# or shorter

oldest = people.max_by(&:age)
#=> #<Person:0x007fef4991d0a8 @age=30>
```

And his or her age with:

```
oldest.age
#=> 30
```

Comment: Cute answer it is ...:)

Comment: `max_by` will also work with the handy ampersand notation; `people.max_by(&:age)`

Answer (score 0):

Say for example your class looks like this:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :firstname, :familyname, :age

  def initialize(firstname, familyname, age)
    @firstname = firstname
    @familyname = familyname
    @age = age
  end
end
```

And say that you have an array of these objects called `people`. Then you could do something like:

```
puts people.max_by { |p| p.age }.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max`

e.g

```
class C
  attr_accessor :age
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end

a,b,c,d = C.new(10), C.new(2), C.new(22), C.new(15)

[a,b,c,d].map(&:age).max #=> 22   
[a.age,b.age,c.age,d.age].max #=> 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've collected all the instances into an array, using one of the techniques shown in [How to get class instances in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365638/how-to-get-class-instances-in-ruby), you can use the technique shown in [Finding the element of a Ruby array with the maximum value for a particular attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038993/finding-the-element-of-a-ruby-array-with-the-maximum-value-for-a-particular-attr) to find the maximum age. For example, if `Foo` is your class and `age` is an attribute of your class, the following should work:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.select{|foo| obj.class == Foo}.max_by {|foo| foo.age}
```